# Avoid CASE on SELECT duplicating Rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Newbie here, I´m struggling to fix a query where the select cases are creating duplicate rows in the results due to the aggregates.

```
select distinct A, B, C, sum(case when X = 1 then N end) as D, sum(case when X = 2 then N end) as E
from table1
where X in (1,2)
group by A, B, C
```

Results

```
A     B    C    D    E
```

```
205  NICE  Y   752    
205  NICE  Y         4356
```

Expected

```
A     B    C    D    E
```

```
205  NICE  Y   752   4356
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Incidentally, if you ever encounter distinct and group by in the same query, you can be 90% certain that the query is flawed.

Comment: I removed distinct, I just added every expression I used to give more details on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
select A, B, C,
       sum(case when X = 1 then N end) as D,
       sum(case when X = 2 then N end) as E
from table1
where X in (1, 2)
group by A, B, C;
```

The `select distinct` is not needed.

If you are getting multiple rows, then the values of `A`, `B`, and `C` are not exactly the same.  This can be due to spaces in the values, hidden characters, characters that look the same in different character sets.

I would suggest that you investigate each column independently:

```
select distinct A
from table1;
```

to figure out where the differences are.

Comment: I found that "C" was the problem, in reality this is a date which is different when X = 1 and X = 2, so to workaround I made an aggregate with MIN(CASE WHEN X = 1) THEN C) END AS DATE

Answer (score 0):

At least temporarily, I would suggest you add `x` to your query. It's possible you have two rows that have the same `a,b,c` but different values for `x`.

```
    select A, B, C, X, 
    sum(case when X = 1 then N end) as D, 
    sum(case when X = 2 then N end) as E
    from table1
    where X in (1,2)
    group by A, B, C, X
```

Also, while I understand this might be a class assignment, I would strongly suggest using a more relevant name for your table than `table1`.